# Erro ao usar cláusula case dentro de um where

Tags: sql, oracle

Estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar usar a cláusula case de um WHERE.

```
ORA-00905: palavra-chave não encontrada
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Erro na linha: 56 Coluna: 39
```

Minha query está da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT ST.cod_tpo_solicitacao,
       ST.dsc_tpo_solicitacao,
       ST.nom_canteiro,
       ST.sta_primeiro_tramite,
       ST.sta_ativo,
       ST.cod_sistema,
       ST.cod_grupo,
       refs.rv_meaning AS DESC_GRUPO
FROM   me_solicitacao_tipos ST 
INNER JOIN me_cg_ref_codes REFS ON To_char(ST.cod_grupo) = REFS.rv_low_value
WHERE  ( ST.cod_sistema = 'LS' )
AND ( ST.cod_companhia = 'XXXXX' )
AND 
    (CASE ST.cod_sistema
        WHEN 'LS' THEN refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS';
        WHEN 'IH' THEN refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_IH';
        WHEN 'CF' THEN refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CF';
        WHEN 'CA' THEN refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CA';
        ELSE ' '
    END)
ORDER  BY cod_tpo_solicitacao, Trim(dsc_tpo_solicitacao);
```

Já realizei algumas dezenas de alterações na query e algumas pesquisas e não consigo identificar o erro.

Comment: Você colocou seu CASE na cláusula WHERE mas parece que se esqueceu do operador de comparação. Não me parece fazer muito sentido, ele não deveria estar na lista de seleção?

Answer (score 1):

Só um detalhe, na sua *query* a primeira condição do `WHERE` é `ST.cod_sistema = 'LS'`. Ou seja, você só está pegando os registros com `cod_sistema` igual a "LS". Sendo assim, no `CASE` não faz mais sentido testar se `cod_sistema` tem um valor diferente (não terá), então bastaria testar se `refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS'`.

Mas, em um caso mais geral, em que você não sabe o valor de `cod_sistema`, você pode sim usar o `CASE` para comparar o valor. Apenas a forma de fazer não como você está tentando.

Basta lembrar que o [`CASE` é uma expressão](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm), e que ela retorna um valor. Então basta comparar este valor com a coluna que você quer verificar. Algo assim:

```
SELECT [colunas]
FROM   me_solicitacao_tipos ST 
INNER JOIN me_cg_ref_codes refs ON ST.cod_grupo = refs.rv_low_value
WHERE ST.cod_companhia = 'CEDAE' -- não incluí o cod_sistema = 'LS', pois aí não faria sentido ter o CASE
AND -- usa o valor da expressão CASE e compara com a coluna rv_domain
    (CASE ST.cod_sistema
        WHEN 'LS' THEN 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS'
        WHEN 'IH' THEN 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_IH'
        WHEN 'CF' THEN 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CF'
        WHEN 'CA' THEN 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CA'
        ELSE ' '
    END) = refs.rv_domain
order by etc...
```

Lembre-se de retirar os ponto-e-vírgula depois de cada `WHEN`.

---

Outra alternativa é colocar todas as possibilidades em uma única condição:

```
WHERE ST.cod_companhia = 'CEDAE'
-- troca o CASE por várias condições
AND (
  (ST.cod_sistema = 'LS' AND refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS') OR
  (ST.cod_sistema = 'IH' AND refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_IH') OR
  (ST.cod_sistema = 'CF' AND refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CF') OR
  (ST.cod_sistema = 'CA' AND refs.rv_domain = 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CA')
)
```

Ou seja, eu testo se `cod_sistema` é "LS" e `rv_domain` é "DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS", **ou** se `cod_sistema` é "IH" e `rv_domain` é "DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_IH", etc...

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Era erro na sintaxe mesmo. Ficou assim:

```
AND refs.rv_domain =  (CASE when
    ST.cod_sistema = 'LS' THEN  'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_LS'
    when ST.cod_sistema = 'IH' THEN  'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_IH'
    when ST.cod_sistema = 'CF' THEN 'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CF'
    when ST.cod_sistema = 'CA' THEN  'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO_CA'
    when ST.cod_sistema = 'CR' THEN  'DA_GRP_TPO_SERVICO'
    ELSE ' '
END)
```

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.